# Why is a variable not changing even if I change the global one?

Tags: python, variables

This is my code, a lot of stuff is in another language so sorry if that's inconvenient.

```
import random


def pradeti_isnaujo():
    answer = input('Ar žaisi dar kartą? taip/ne ').lower()
    if answer == 't' or answer == 'taip':
        zaisti()
    else:
        pass


def naujas_zodis():
    words = ['katė', 'šuo', 'python', 'mašina', 'gyvatė', 'jonas']
    return random.choice(words)


alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
word = naujas_zodis()
letters_guessed = []
tries = 10
guessed = False
letters_word = len(word)


def zaisti():

    global alphabet
    global word
    global letters_guessed
    global tries
    global guessed
    global letters_word

    print('Žodis sudarytas iš', len(word), 'raidžių.')
    print(len(word) * '*')
    while guessed == False and tries > 0:
        print('Liko ' + str(tries) + ' spėjimai')
        guess = input('Spėjama raidė arba žodis: ').lower()
        # 1 - user inputs a letter

        if len(guess) == 1:
            if guess not in alphabet:
                print('Neįrašėte raidės.')
            elif guess in letters_guessed:
                print('Ši raidė jau buvo spėta.')
            elif guess not in word:
                print('Ši raidė netinka :(')
                letters_guessed.append(guess)
                tries -= 1
            elif guess in word:
                print('Ši raidė yra spėjamame žodyje!')
                letters_guessed.append(guess)
            else:
                print('error!')

        # 2 - pilnas žodis
        elif len(guess) == len(word):
            if guess == word:
                print('Atspėjote žodį!')
                guessed = True
            else:
                print('Neatspėjote :(')
                tries -= 1

        # 3 - ilgesnis žodis negu turimas žodis.
        elif guessed > letters_word:
            print('Žodis yra trumpesnis negu jį spėjote.')
            tries -= 1

        status = ''
        if not guessed:
            for letter in word:
                if letter in letters_guessed:
                    status += letter
                else:
                    status += '*'
            print(status)

        if status == word:
            print('Atspėjote žodį!')
            guessed = True
        elif tries == 0:
            print('Nebeliko spėjimų.')

        elif guessed < letters_word:
            print('Žodis yra ilgesnis negu jį spėjote.')

            tries -= 1

            status = ''
        if guessed:
            for letter in word:
                if letter in letters_guessed:
                    status += letter
                else:
                    status += '*'
            print(status)

    pradeti_isnaujo()


zaisti()
```

It's basically coded for hangman, I have this weird bug where even if I change the global variable tries to let's say 5 it will still display that I have 10 tries left, and I have a few lines of code that tell if the word you're guessing is longer or shorter than the one you have to guess, after saying that your guessed word is shorter or longer it should take one try away but it still stays at 10, the only thing that works is the if statement that checks if you guessed the right letter and it takes away the try with no problems, keep in mind all of this is in one function. can it be a bug in the interpreter where it doesn't look at the new code I wrote?

Comment: try nonlocal instead of global

Comment: Before each of the "tries -= 1" there is a "print" to show some message. Do these messages appear?

Answer (score 1):

I tried and it's working fine.

```py
import random


def pradeti_isnaujo():
    answer = input('Ar žaisi dar kartą? taip/ne ').lower()
    if answer == 't' or answer == 'taip':
        zaisti()
    else:
        pass


def naujas_zodis():
    words = ['katė', 'šuo', 'python', 'mašina', 'gyvatė', 'jonas']
    words = ['python']
    return random.choice(words)


alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
word = naujas_zodis()
letters_guessed = []
tries = 3
guessed = False
letters_word = len(word)

def guess_letter(guess):
    global letters_guessed
    global tries

    if guess not in alphabet:
        return 'Neįrašėte raidės.'
    elif guess in letters_guessed:
        return 'Ši raidė jau buvo spėta.'
    elif guess not in word:
        letters_guessed.append(guess)
        tries -= 1
        return 'Ši raidė netinka :('
    elif guess in word:
        letters_guessed.append(guess)
        return 'Ši raidė yra spėjamame žodyje!'
    else:
        return 'error!'

def guess_word(guess):
    global guessed
    global tries

    if guess == word:
        guessed = True
        return 'Atspėjote žodį!'
    else:
        tries -= 1
        return 'Neatspėjote :('

def zaisti():

    global alphabet
    global word
    global letters_guessed
    global tries
    global guessed
    global letters_word

    print('Žodis sudarytas iš', len(word), 'raidžių.')
    print(len(word) * '*')
    while guessed == False and tries > 0:
        print('Liko ' + str(tries) + ' spėjimai')
        guess = input('Spėjama raidė arba žodis: ').lower()
        # 1 - user inputs a letter

        if len(guess) == 1:
            print(guess_letter(guess))

        # 2 - pilnas žodis
        elif len(guess) == len(word):
            print(guess_word(guess))

        # 3 - ilgesnis žodis negu turimas žodis.
        elif guessed > letters_word:
            print('Žodis yra trumpesnis negu jį spėjote.')
            tries -= 1

        status = ''
        if not guessed:
            for letter in word:
                if letter in letters_guessed:
                    status += letter
                else:
                    status += '*'
            print(status)

        if status == word:
            print('Atspėjote žodį!')
            guessed = True
        elif tries == 0:
            print('Nebeliko spėjimų.')

        elif guessed < letters_word:
            print('Žodis yra ilgesnis negu jį spėjote.')

            tries -= 1

            status = ''
        if guessed:
            for letter in word:
                if letter in letters_guessed:
                    status += letter
                else:
                    status += '*'
            print(status)

    pradeti_isnaujo()


zaisti()
```

> output

```
Žodis sudarytas iš 6 raidžių.
******
Liko 3 spėjimai
Spėjama raidė arba žodis: p
Ši raidė yra spėjamame žodyje!
p*****
Žodis yra ilgesnis negu jį spėjote.
Liko 2 spėjimai
Spėjama raidė arba žodis: y
Ši raidė yra spėjamame žodyje!
py****
Žodis yra ilgesnis negu jį spėjote.
Liko 1 spėjimai
Spėjama raidė arba žodis:
```